# Making <p> behave like <br>

Tags: html, css

I want to use `<p>` instead of `<br><br>` since it takes less space and I can change how big of a gap it will create (changing the top margin of p).

However when using a floating image using `<p>` will make the row appear below the image instead of beside it.

I was think about setting the display property to inline but that makes the `<p>` not changing row at all.

So, how can i make p behave like br?

Comment: rather than drive every web developer after you crazy, maybe you should just use the `<br />` tag? Or my personal favorite `<div>&nbsp;</div>`

Comment: First of all, `<p>` is not `<br>` and will never "behave the same". Secondly, maybe you could illustrate your question with some code to clarify where the problem is?

Comment: @Mike - Agree with hunter.  Sorry Mike, this is just a really bad idea.  Standards exist for a reason, and writing <br/> just really isn't that hard.

Comment: While we're at it, let's change div to be the img tag, h1 be the h6 tag, and script to be the ul tag.  I get really sick and tired of having to write <script> all the time.  BTW can you guys help me debug my code later?

Comment: @Mike: I have to point out that you still have to close your `<p>` and <br/> should be self closing, like I just did.

Comment: You guys just clearly dont understand the purpose of what I'm asking. But never mind, you're too rude for me to bother to clarify if. Really, I know I'm the one looking for favor here but everyone's a comedian it would seem.

Comment: ummm no @Mike - you're the one that's using `<br /><br />` for separating content - to us, you're the comedian :)

Comment: @Sime Vidas - Sime's comment almost had me falling out of my chair.  We are all a bunch of comedians :) lol.

Comment: Does this help? http://jsfiddle.net/VVWu5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
p { height:(designated height of space); }
```

note that this only works if the line is very short and not breaking; or you will end up with a mess.

Its not really good practice to change the br tag...I mean that's why standards exist. like @hunter said before.

Comment: Thanks friend, I'll try it out though I suspect it won't do the trick.

Comment: It's odd but the behaviour differs for me, I must have a glitch in the rest of my code somewhere. Your solution provided the same results as mine did, although I thought mine didn't work it worked now when I retried. I'll just scout around my code.

Comment: hey i didnt really read this but i googled this it might help... http://www.webmasterclip.com/story/how-replace-br-pp

Comment: @Mike - Sorry everyone's being so hard on you, but if you use non-standard HTML elements in your code, it creates what's called technical debt.  Essentially, you continue to build up bug after bug after bug until suddenly you find that nothing works as you'd expect.  Here is a link here to help you out:  http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/02/paying-down-your-technical-debt.html  Don't let the comedians scare you away as Stack Overflow is a great resource.  :)

Answer (score 7):

You don't 'make `<p>` behave like `<br>`', you use the right element for the job. If you're wrapping paragraphs of text, you use a `<p>` tag.

Outside of HTML emails, I don't ever see a use for a `<br><br>`.

Comment: +1. I've actually redesigned a site that for some reason had a sidebar (on every page because there wasn't a template) that contained ~30 `<br>`s in a row, with nothing after them. Thus, I completely agree with your br-br statement.

Comment: The only good use of `<br>` for me at least is for poetry, though for that even CSS's `white-space` property is more useful.

Comment: Yes, `<br>` is OK for some things, it also gets used for things like formatting addresses properly.... double `<br>`s though are not cool.